# PHP Script to search for word on web page

Tags: php, html, parsing

Can someone please show me how to change the following PHP script to say "found" if the site http://www.stutteringjohnsmith.com has the word "standup" in it and to say "not found" if it does not

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.stutteringjohnsmmith.com/#/0');
$regex = '/Page 1 of (.+?) results/';
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
var_dump($match);
echo $match[1];
?>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
<?php
$data = file_get_contents('http://www.stutteringjohnsmmith.com/#/0');
$regex = '/standup/';    //<----
preg_match($regex,$data,$match);
var_dump($match);
echo $match[1];
?>
```

lol?

Answer (score 4):

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents('http://www.stutteringjohnsmith.com/#/0');
echo (stristr ($text, 'standup')) ? 'found' : 'not found';
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using a wordpress Domain (http://stutteringjohnsmith.wordpress.com/)

The following will work:

```
$data = file_get_contents('http://stutteringjohnsmith.wordpress.com/');
$regex = '/standup/';    

if (preg_match($regex, $data)) {
    echo "found";
} else {
    echo "not found";
}
```